# How can I get top5 max() values per month pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get top5 max() values per month?
CUrrently, I'm getting the max value for each month.

```
df1 = df['balance'].resample('M').max()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe need [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html), but not implemented for `resample` yet, so need [`Resampler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.apply.html):

```
df1 = df['balance'].resample('M').apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(5))
```